# How to send list of entity class as response in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 5 entity class in spring. I have to encapsulate these all class in one class and collect all the values of that class in spring controller and send response.

If you have any idea please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class like A and declare all 5 classes in this class like sample :

```js
public class Response {
   private A a;
   private B b;
   private C c;
   private D d;
   private E e;

   // getter and setters
}
```

Fill above response object and return from the controller like

```js
@RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody Response getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String id) {

  Response response = new Response();
    
    // add A,B,C,D,E to response object
  response.setA();
    response.setB();
    response.setC();
    response.setD();
    response.setE();
     return response;

   }
```

@ResponseBody annotation will convert the response as json internally using message converters

Comment: your answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write test case for that by using Junit

Comment: Thanks. Refer this link may help to write junit test case using spring controllers - https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

Create a new entity which contains the other entity references as fields

`public class MyResponse {
          private Entity1 entity1;
}`

Include all 5 entity as fields in MyResponse class and **set the entities** accordingly and then return MyResponse directly or in a response entity as `ResponseEntity.ok(myResponse)`